# Python Sockets using stoppbit

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send more than one image file from a client to the server with sockets.
My problem is that I can't get the stoppbit (or word) working.

client:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("server",port))
#grab image ...
s.send(imagedata)
s.send("#FINISH#")
s.close()
```

server:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("",port))
s.listen(1)

c,a = s.accept()

while True:
    imagedata = c.recv(1024)

    if not imagedata or "#FINISH#" in imagedata:
        komm.close()
        break

    image = image + imagedata


s.close()
#remove stoppword and save image ...
```

This is only a simple example but you can see the problem. I can't fetch the "#FINISH#" because the second send (client) appends the string (sometimes) to the imagedata. I know it's because of the bufsize of recv. How should I do it?

Comment: You have to actually design a protocol before you start coding. The protocol should specify how the receiver identifies where the various parts of the data are.

Comment: There is no 'stopbit' in either TCP or your code. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't send a "stop bit", instead first send the length of the data in a fixed-length field.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do so, check the "stop bit" in the full data you've received, i.e. 
`"#FINISH#" == image[-len("#FINISH#"):]`.